# Program to construct list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging

I am trying to write a program that takes in a dictionary of frequencies and an integer, and returns a list of tuples containing all the words that appear more than min_times.

```
def words_often(freqs, min_times):
tuple_list = []
for key in freqs:
    word_list = []
    if freqs[key] > min_times:
        store_value = freqs[key]
        for key2 in freqs:
            if freqs[key2] == store_value:
                word_list += [key2]
    if freqs[key] not in tuple_list:
        tuple_list += [(word_list, store_value)]
return tuple_list


#test program
freqs = {'yeah':15, 'one': 1, 'crazy': 3, 'lonely': 1}

print(words_often(freqs, 0))
```

There's something wrong however, the return value for the test above, is :

```
[([‘yeah’], 15), ([‘one’, ‘lonely’], 1), ([‘crazy’], 3), ([‘one’, ‘lonely’], 1)]
```

This return value shouldn't have the last entry, because it's a duplicate.

How can I make my code simpler, because a lot is going on and I can't determine the problem.

Edit: I need the words inside the tuples to be grouped in lists. For example the first entry should be (['yeah'], 15) and for words that have the same value (one and lonely), I need them to be grouped like (['one', 'lonely'], 1)

Comment: @crook Sets/dicts can't, but tuples can.

Comment: yeah my bad . confused with set and tuple. ty

Comment: I am performing research for an article and plan on referencing this question in it. As part of that research, I am wondering if everyone who interacted with this question could message me and let me know how many years they have been coding in python. I would truly appreciate any and all help any of you are willing to provide. Thank you in advance. - Sage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to group keys by values, you could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
data = {'yeah':15, 'one': 4, 'crazy': 3, 'lonely': 4}
min_times = 3

get_value = lambda kv: kv[1]
sorted_data = sorted(data.items(), key= get_value, reverse=True)
print(sorted_data)
# [('yeah', 15), ('one', 4), ('lonely', 4), ('crazy', 3)]


print([([v[0] for v in vs], k) for k,vs in groupby(sorted_data, key= get_value) if k > min_times])
# [(['yeah'], 15), (['one', 'lonely'], 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use collections.defaultdict

```
freqs = {'yeah':15, 'one': 1, 'crazy': 3, 'lonely': 1}
from collections import defaultdict
def words_often(freqs, min_times):
    d_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for k,v in freqs.items():
        d_dict[v].append(k)
    return [(v,k) for k,v in d_dict.items() if k>min_times]

print(words_often(freqs, 0))
```

Output:

```
[(['yeah'], 15), (['one', 'lonely'], 1), (['crazy'], 3)]
```

Comment: But your version doesn't account for min_times

Answer (score 0):

[List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) may make your code simpler.

```
from collections import defaultdict

def words_often(freqs, min_times):
    words = [(key, freqs[key]) for key in freqs if freqs[key] >= min_times]
    # words = [('yeah', 15), ('one', 1), ('crazy', 3), ('lonely', 1)]

    d = defaultdict(list)
    for word, freq in words:
        d[freq].append(word)
    # d = {15: ['yeah'], 1: ['one', 'lonely'], 3: ['crazy']}

    return [(d[freq], freq) for freq in d]

# Test
freqs = {'yeah':15, 'one': 1, 'crazy': 3, 'lonely': 1, 'zero':0}
print(words_often(freqs, 1))
# [(['yeah'], 15), (['one', 'lonely'], 1), (['crazy'], 3)]
```

Comment: I understand what you're doing here, but I need the words inside the tuples to be grouped in lists. For example the first entry should be (['yeah'], 15) and for words that have the same value (one and lonely), I need them to be grouped like (['one', 'lonely'], 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
freqs = {'yeah':15, 'one': 1, 'crazy': 3, 'lonely': 1}
m = 0
from collections import defaultdict
def answer(d, m):
    out = defaultdict(list)
    for e, i in d.items():
        if i > m:
            out[i].append(e)
    return [(e, i) for i, e in out.items()]
```

This will work.

Comment: @sula7ifa check this out now.

Answer (score 0):

This will return a `list` of `tuples` from a given `dict` if the value in the given `dict` is greater then the given minimum requirements:

```
def convert(items, min):
    return [(key, items[key]) for key in items.iterkeys() if items[key] > min]
```

For example, with your shown `dict`:

```
freqs = {'yeah': 15, 'one': 1, 'crazy': 3, 'lonely': 1}
convert(freqs, 0)
# [('crazy', 3), ('lonely', 1), ('yeah', 15), ('one', 1)]
```

This basically does a `for loop` on a single line that is called a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Read about them, they will save your life.

---

If you want the first value in the `tuple` to be a `list`, the simplest way would be to add `[]` around the insertion of the value:

```
def convert(items, min):
    return [([key], items[key]) for key in items.iterkeys() if items[key] > min]
```

And another example with your given `dict`:

```
freqs = {'yeah': 15, 'one': 1, 'crazy': 3, 'lonely': 1}
convert(freqs, 0)
# [(['crazy'], 3), (['lonely'], 1), (['yeah'], 15), (['one'], 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

[(word, freq) for freq, word in (
    pd.Series(freqs)
      .reset_index()
      .groupby(0, as_index=False)
      .agg(lambda x: list(x))
      .values
)]

# [(['lonely', 'one'], 1), (['crazy'], 3), (['yeah'], 15)]
```

Whatever solution you end up going with, it may be helpful to consider that this is a `reduce` operation on word frequency, and frequency occupies the value slot in your `word:freq` key:value pairs.

`reduce` and/or `groupby` operations work by collapsing on *keys*, and then creating some aggregation of the associated *values*.  That's why you see a number of these answers reversing `freqs` at some point, to get things in shape for the `reduce` operation.